# Compilar archivo.py versión 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, compilar

Buenas tardes después de varios meses terminé mi primer programa grande que construye un documento en word, ahora el problema es que usé la versión Python 3.7 y he intentado compilarlo pero no me resulta como espero, se muestra mi aplicación pero al ejecutarla solo me crea el documento vacío en mi laptop pero al probarla en la computadora donde la cree si me bota el documento rellenado con los datos.
Estuve leyendo sobre compilación y veo que en la versión 3.7 no esta bien implementada.
Podrían darme alguna solución? o que más necesitan saber para ayudarme
Mi programa tiene estas librerías

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
import datetime
import re
from docx import Document
import locale
```

Comment: Hola CelestHaku ¿A que te refieres con compilación? Python no es un lenguaje compilado, es interpretado ¿Te refieres a crear ejecutables con pyinstaller, cx_freeze, etc (que no es compilar de todas formas)? ¿A que te refieres con  "leyendo sobre compilación y veo que en la versión 3.7 no esta bien implementada"?

Comment: @FJSevilla mil disculpas, así es crear un .exe lo he intentado 2 veces con pyinstaller pero cuando lo llevo a otra máquina no resuelta igual, solo cuando lo uso en mi computadora